# S3 Bucket Policy to allow S3 Access to Current Authenicated user in AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have an application where I am using Cognito to authenticate users and giving temporary access to AWS Console but that user is able to see all other buckets, I want that user just should be able to see or access buckets created by him.

Currently, I have given S3FullAccess Policy to Cognito users. Can anyone suggest which policy I should attach?

As per my R&D, I can some policies are there that can restrict particular user or allow particular user but my users will be dynamic, so I cannot hard-code the values and also policies like allowing/restricting access to particular buckets, I want only users who create buckets should be able to access not other users.

This is something which i found

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "home/",
                    "home/${aws:userid}/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}/*"
        ]
    }
]
      }
```

But this is listing all buckets and the only accessible bucket is what put in the code above, I want for new user, it should show nothing and as it creates, it should show that only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be easy and you will need to create your own policy and enforce some conventions.  You have 3 options.

But first, if each user just needs their own S3 space look at S3 Prefix [here](
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/)    Also, you can do this on the S3 resource bucket.  I have a template for doing this [here in gitlab](https://gitlab.com/daringway/aws-resource-policy-templates/blob/master/s3/s3-private-home.json)

Now back to answering your question.

- <s>Option 1; They will need to set a tag when they create the bucket where an "owner" tag is equal to their identity.</s> I striked this one out because despite being listed in the IAM policy I'm pretty sure it doesn't work with S3.
- Option 2: The prefix of the bucket name is equal to their identity.

Then you can use the feature of variables and tags in IAM Policy. [Read here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-tags)

Note that coginto users are web federated identities so the variable aws:username is not aviable for you.  Use the aws:userid variable and the value will be role id:caller-specified-role-name  where role id is the unique id of the role and the caller-specified-role-name is specified by the RoleSessionName parameter passed to the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity request

- Option 3: Use IAM Access Policy

I can not find a link to the how to at the moment.  But from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/) is a detailed description.

> Q: How do I control what a federated user is allowed to do when signed in to the console? 
>   When you request temporary security credentials for your federated
>   user using an AssumeRole API, you can optionally include an access
>   policy with the request. The federated user’s privileges are the
>   intersection of permissions granted by the access policy passed with
>   the request and the access policy attached to the IAM role that was
>   assumed. The access policy passed with the request cannot elevate the
>   privileges associated with the IAM role being assumed. When you
>   request temporary security credentials for your federated user using
>   the GetFederationToken API, you must provide an access control policy
>   with the request. The federated user’s privileges are the intersection
>   of the permissions granted by the access policy passed with the
>   request and the access policy attached to the IAM user that was used
>   to make the request. The access policy passed with the request cannot
>   elevate the privileges associated with the IAM user used to make the
>   request. These federated user permissions apply to both API access and
>   actions taken within the AWS Management Console.

The nice thing about this approach is you programmatically create the access policy.

Comment: I am not able to create such policy, could you help me with that?

Comment: If this is possible for EC2?

Comment: No it's not possible at this time for EC2.  The IAM documents actually has a paragraph where it states it's possible but it's not.

Comment: @ManishGoyal Can you provide more details on the error as I didn't provide an actual policy and not sure what you are referencing.

Comment: Policy is working which u provided in GitLab link but nothing like private space I am ggetting